# Average count data from pivot table - Need assistance

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I am working on a little project to deliver application that pull data from database to show average of shipment made each day of the week. I have made some progress and have now script that count all of shipment but because I count them based on varchar type of column also I need solution  to calculate average for each day of the week separately.

So far I end up with something as follows:

```
SELECT [Monday], [Tuesday], [Wednesday], [Thursday], [Friday], [Saturday], [Sunday]
    FROM (
        SELECT DATENAME(dw, Shipment.Date) AS DayWeek, Shipment.ID
        FROM Shipment
        WHERE  MONTH(Shipment.Date)= MONTH(DATEADD(MONTH, DATEDIFF(MONTH, 0, 'OCTOBER 2016' ), 0)) AND
        Shipment.Bur = 'GB'
) AS src
pivot (
    COUNT(ID) FOR DayWeek IN ([Monday], [Tuesday], [Wednesday], [Thursday], [Friday], [Saturday], [Sunday])
 ) AS pvt
```

I appreciate much any hint or help as it is looks like I run out of ideas at the moment and can get any further to deliver right solution.

Comment: Can you post sample data and expected result

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the answer for my question by browsing through stackoverflow encountering on similar problem posted by one of the user.

```
    SELECT [Day], SUM(q.Totals) AS "Weekly Shipment Amount", AVG(Totals) AS [Avg]
FROM
(
    SELECT 
  w = DATEDIFF(WEEK, 0, DATE),
      [Day]  = DATENAME(Weekday, DATE),
      Totals = COUNT(*)
    FROM dbo.Shipment
    --INNER JOIN FCLI (NOLOCK) ON FCLI.CCLI = FEXP.CCLI 
      WHERE (BUR = 'GB' AND
      Shipment.Date >= '20160601' AND Shipment.Date <= '20160630')

    GROUP BY 
        DATEDIFF(WEEK, 0, Date),
        DATENAME(WEEKDAY, Date),
        DATEPART(WEEKDAY, Date)
  ) AS q
GROUP BY [Day]
ORDER BY [DaY] ASC;
```

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest dispensing with the `pivot` altogether and putting on the results in separate rows:

```
SELECT DayWeek, AVG(cnt) 
FROM (SELECT s.Date, DATENAME(dw, s.Date) AS DayWeek, COUNT(*) as cnt
      FROM Shipment s
      WHERE MONTH(s.Date) = MONTH(DATEADD(MONTH, DATEDIFF(MONTH, 0, 'OCTOBER 2016' ), 0)) AND
            s.Bur = 'GB'
      GROUP BY s.Date
     ) d
GROUP BY DayWeek
ORDER BY MIN(s.Date);
```